# SimpleXML: Value and Attribute on same Node

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

Is it possible, to address a nodes Attributes and Value with SimpleXML?
For example in tag "from":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from name="test">Jani</from> 
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Dont forget me this weekend!</body>
  </note>
```

I couldn't find a way to address the content of the node in my code.
My example code for this XML would be:

```
public class Note 
{
    @Element(name = "to")
    private String to;

    @Element(name = "from")
    private Sender from;

    @Element(name = "heading")
    private String heading;

    @Element(name = "body")
    private String body;
    
}

public class Sender 
{

    private String content;

    @Attribute(name = "name")
    private String attribute;

}
```

Now im looking for a annotation for Sender.content which addresses the value note/from/Jani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official documentation, you can use the annotation `@Text`:

Example below:

**Adding text and attributes to elements**

> As can be seen from the previous example annotating a primitive such
> as a String with the Element annotation will result in text been added
> to a names XML element. However it is also possible to add text to an
> element that contains attributes. An example of such a class schema is
> shown below.

```
@Root
public class Entry {

   @Attribute
   private String name;

   @Attribute
   private int version;     

   @Text
   private String value;

   public int getVersion() {
      return version;           
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public String getValue() {
      return value;              
   }
}
```

> Here the class is annotated in such a way that an element contains two
> attributes named version and name. It also contains a text annotation
> which specifies text to add to the generated element. Below is an
> example XML document that can be generated using the specified class
> schema.

```
<entry version='1' name='name'>
   Some example text within an element
</entry>
```

> The rules that govern the use of the Text annotation are that there
> can only be one per schema class. Also, this annotation cannot be used
> with the Element annotation. Only the Attribute annotation can be used
> with it as this annotation does not add any content within the owning
> element.

---

Your code will then look like:

```
public class Sender 
{

    @Text
    private String content;

    @Attribute(name = "name")
    private String attribute;

}
```

http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php